# How to sort a class array with multiple fields in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have this code that asks a user for book titles, authors, and page counts and stores them in a class array. It then asks the user how they would like the books sorted. The code works but my professor said it could be more efficient at sorting. Unfortunately, my book doesn't go over the comparator method or collections until my second java course, so I can't use those. I need to make it so it has less duplication, but I'm all out of ideas.

Here's the current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class LibraryBookSort
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String bookTitle, bookAuthor, bookPC, sortOption;
      String temp = "", temp2 = "", temp3 = "";
      int a, b, x;
      LibraryBook[] book = new LibraryBook[5];
      for(x = 0; x < book.length; ++x)
      {
         bookTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a book title:");
         bookAuthor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the book's author:");
         bookPC = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the book's page count:");
         book[x] = new LibraryBook();
         book[x].setTitle(bookTitle);
         book[x].setAuthor(bookAuthor);
         book[x].setPageCount(bookPC);
      }
      sortOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How would you like the books to be sorted?"
         + "\nPress 1 to sort by title \nPress 2 to sort by author \nPress 3 to sort by page count");
      int comparisonsToMake = book.length - 1;
      switch(sortOption)
      {
         case "1":            
            for(a = 0; a < book.length - 1; ++a)
            {
               for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)
               {
                  if(book[b].getTitle().compareTo(book[b + 1].getTitle()) > 0)
                  {
                     temp = book[b + 1].getTitle();
                     temp2 = book[b + 1].getAuthor();
                     temp3 = book[b + 1].getPageCount();
                     book[b + 1].setTitle(book[b].getTitle());
                     book[b + 1].setAuthor(book[b].getAuthor());
                     book[b + 1].setPageCount(book[b].getPageCount());
                     book[b].setTitle(temp);
                     book[b].setAuthor(temp2);
                     book[b].setPageCount(temp3);
                  }
               }
               --comparisonsToMake;
            }
            break;
         case "2":
            for(a = 0; a < book.length - 1; ++a)
            {
               for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)
               {
                  if(book[b].getAuthor().compareTo(book[b + 1].getAuthor()) > 0)
                  {
                     temp = book[b + 1].getTitle();
                     temp2 = book[b + 1].getAuthor();
                     temp3 = book[b + 1].getPageCount();
                     book[b + 1].setTitle(book[b].getTitle());
                     book[b + 1].setAuthor(book[b].getAuthor());
                     book[b + 1].setPageCount(book[b].getPageCount());
                     book[b].setTitle(temp);
                     book[b].setAuthor(temp2);
                     book[b].setPageCount(temp3);
                  }
               }
               --comparisonsToMake;
            }
            break;
         case "3":            
            for(a = 0; a < book.length - 1; ++a)
            {
               for(b = 0; b < comparisonsToMake; ++b)
               {
                  if(book[b].getPageCount().compareTo(book[b + 1].getPageCount()) > 0)
                  {
                     temp = book[b + 1].getTitle();
                     temp2 = book[b + 1].getAuthor();
                     temp3 = book[b + 1].getPageCount();
                     book[b + 1].setTitle(book[b].getTitle());
                     book[b + 1].setAuthor(book[b].getAuthor());
                     book[b + 1].setPageCount(book[b].getPageCount());
                     book[b].setTitle(temp);
                     book[b].setAuthor(temp2);
                     book[b].setPageCount(temp3);
                  }
               }
               --comparisonsToMake;
            }
            break;
         default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is an invalid option."
               + "\nThe books will not be sorted");
            break;
      }
      for(x = 0; x < book.length; ++x)
         book[x].display();      
   }
}
```

does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: If you have **working** code that you would like tips for improvement on, [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a place to look at.

Comment: Let me get this straight... you're being asked to do a common task for which there is already a well-designed and flexible API, but you're forbidden to use that API because it hasn't been taught yet?

Find another teacher.

Comment: @BrodoFraggins Sometimes learning what lies behind that API is useful. You may not need to implement your own sorting algorithm in the future, but learning how it's done could be a nice thing to know. Sometimes teachers don't want students taking shortcuts because then they may miss fundamentals that might be needed later.

Comment: you can put all that code inside the if in your cases in a separate method, since it is exactly the same anyway

Comment: @user3580294 Teaching beginners how to implement their own data structures and sorting algorithms only plants the idea that they should roll their own inferior ad hoc solutions to everything.  Yes, I'm aware that nearly every CS curriculum starts that way.  Nearly every CS curriculum is wrong!  Beginners should be taught the real-world skill of evaluating existing solutions and choosing the correct one for the job.  Most of my job as a professional programmer is cleaning up after idiots with degrees who were never taught this.

Comment: @BrodoFraggins Uh, no, that's not true at all. Idiots with degrees will be idiots regardless of what you teach them. Why does teaching data structures and sorting algorithms have to be mutually exclusive with evaluating existing solutions? The former helps with the latter. You can't deny that. It doesn't mean that you can't pick the proper library. I'm sorry that that's your job, and it sounds extremely painful, but I don't see a problem with teaching data structures/sorting algorithms in a properly structured CS course. Unless it's the "properly structured" that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if "could be more efficient at sorting" means less code, encapsulate

```
                 temp = book[b + 1].getTitle();
                 temp2 = book[b + 1].getAuthor();
                 temp3 = book[b + 1].getPageCount();
                 book[b + 1].setTitle(book[b].getTitle());
                 book[b + 1].setAuthor(book[b].getAuthor());
                 book[b + 1].setPageCount(book[b].getPageCount());
                 book[b].setTitle(temp);
                 book[b].setAuthor(temp2);
                 book[b].setPageCount(temp3);
```

as a function

if "could be more efficient" at sorting means complexity, use a different sorting algorithm

Comment: This wouldn't make his code more efficient. If anything, the stack manipulation of a function would be (*mind you a small amount*) less efficient.

Comment: edited to clarify between potentially different meanings of "more efficient"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the bubblesort algorithm, which has an O(n^2) average case complexity. I would suggest replacing it with Quicksort which has O(nlogn) average case complexity.